# Class Method to 'Know' Class Name in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, metaprogramming

I want an inherited ruby class to 'know' its class name via a class method. This is best illustrated by a contrived example:

```
class Parent
  def self.whoami
    ??
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  #No code should be needed.
end
```

So I should be able to call:

```
Parent.whomai
```

and expect a return of "Parent" I should then be able to call:

```
Child.whoami
```

and expect a return of "Child" I have a feeling that in conventional languages this might not be possible. But Ruby's metaprogramming model has amazed me before. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A Class Method is a method where the CLASS is the receiver, so to find the object upon which the method is invoked (what you appear to be trying to do here) simply inspect the value of `self`.

```
class Parent
  def self.whoami
    self
  end
end

class Child < Parent
end

puts Parent.whoami #=> Parent
puts Child.whoami #=> Child
```

Comment: That seemed way too easy. Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with [`Module#name`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/ruby-1.9/classes/Module.html#M000913) and why the double `puts`?

Comment: There is no reason to have a method that returns self, use the object directly: `puts Parent`. Puts is calling Parent.to_s behind the scenes to get a string name of the class.

Comment: If you're just dumping debug info with `puts`, this is fine. But take note that puts calls an implicit `.to_s` in there, so it *appears* you're getting just the name. But in fact, you're getting the class definition. So, if you're using that value somewhere that .to_s doesn't get injected for you, you'll be better off with Parent.name, or possibly Parent.to_s. Granted, that's a fairly esoteric situation...but I just ran into it in the real world.

Answer (score 15):

The method to get the name of a class (module, actually) is just [`Module#name`](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/trunk/Module.html#method-i-name). There's no need to write your own:

```
Parent.name # => 'Parent'
Child.name  # => 'Child'
```

However, in Ruby, there really is no such thing as a "class name" as there is in some other languages. In Ruby, a class is simply an object like any other object which gets assigned to a variable like any other variable.

All the `Module#name` method does is loop through all the constants in the system and check whether the module has been assigned to any one of them, and return that constant's name or `nil` if it cannot find any.

So, just like any other object, the "name" of a class is *really* nothing but whatever variable you use to refer to it.

Example:

```
foo = Class.new
foo.name # => nil
```

Now, the "name" of the class is `foo`. However, `Module#name` returns `nil`, because `foo` is not a constant.

```
bar = foo
bar.name # => nil
```

Now, the "name" of the class is *both* `foo` and `bar`, but `Module#name` obviously still returns `nil`.

```
BAZ = foo
foo.name # => 'BAZ'
```

Now, since the class has been assigned to a constant, that constant's name will be considered that class's name …

```
BAZ = nil
foo.name # => 'BAZ'
```

… even after the constant has been assigned to something different and …

```
QUX = foo
QUX.name # => 'BAZ'
```

… even after the class has been assigned to a different constant.

`Module#to_s` uses `Module#name` if it is not `nil`, so, to print the name of a class, you simply do

```
puts Parent
```

There's really absolutely no need for all the complex fluff in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Isn't that what `Parent.class` will tell you?

```
class Parent
  def self.whoami
    self.to_s
  end
end

class Child < Parent
end

> Parent.whoami
=> "Parent"
> Child.whoami
=> "Child"
```

Comment: If its a class method, `self` will return the class

Comment: What's wrong with [`Module#name`](http://Ruby-Doc.Org/ruby-1.9/classes/Module.html#M000913)?

Comment: @Jörg I was assuming that he was doing something a little more complicated than a class-method that returned a name, but you're right that `Module#name` is the correct way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you class:

```
class ABC
 def self.some_method
   self.name #it will return 'ABC'
   self.name.constantize #it will return ABC
 end
end
```